# In a bipartite graph, any cycle of length equal to the girth is a retract.

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

This is an exercise from the book *Algebraic Graph Theory by Godsil and Royle*.

> Show that in a bipartite graph, any cycle of length equal to the girth is a retract.

We say that a subgraph $Y$ of $X$ is a retract, if there is a homomorphism $f:X\to Y$ such that $f|Y$ is the identity map.

I have no idea how to approach this, I can gather a few things from the graph being bipartite, such as that the girth must be even, or that there is a homomorphism from it to $K_2$. But I'm having a hard time piecing it together.

Comment: It's not a full answer, but if you have access to Hell and Nesetril's "Graphs and Homomorphisms", then you can get a proof of the analogous result for reflexive, non-bipartite graphs (Proposition 2.50 and 2.51).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: consider a vertex on the minimum length cycle, and label the other vertices of the graph by their distance from it. See if you can use this to define a retraction.
(Basically, use the previous exercise in the book).

You may also find it helpful to know that, if $u$ is any vertex of a connected bipartite graph, then the vertices even distance from $u$ are one partite set of $G$, and the vertices odd distance from $u$ are the other partite set.

Proof sketch:

> Let $C = v_0, v_1, \dots, v_{k-1}$ be a minimum length cycle in $G$. For $u\in G$, define a label $j: V(G)\to \mathbb{N}$ by: $$j(u) = \begin{cases}d(v_0, u) &\text{ if } d(v_0,u) < k\\ k-1 &\text{ if }d(v_0,u)\geq k,\text{ and } d(v_0,u)\text{ is even}\\k-2 &\text{ if }d(v_0,u)\geq k,\text{ and } d(v_0,u)\text{ is odd}\end{cases}$$ Then we define a retraction $r:V(G)\to V(C)$ by $r(u) = v_{j(u)}$. I'll leave you to check that it's a retraction. In fact, this map $r$ is even a retraction from $G-\{v_0v_{k-1}\}$ onto the path $C-\{v_0v_{k-1}\}$.

Comment: I have a question about the retraction. If the vertex is at an odd distance of $v_0$ and the distance is greater than $k$ then it is mapped to $v_k$, but $v_k$ is not in the cycle, so $r$ would be mapping some vertex of $G$ to some vertex that is not in $V(C)$, right?

Comment: Apologies! The $k$ should be a $k-2$. I'll fix it now.

Comment: Also by this logic, some vertices that are not in the cycle but are neighbors to some vertex in the cycle would be in the image of $r$ but are not in $V(C)$.

Comment: Oh wait, that last comment is incorrect, I got it now

Comment: But I think that the first condition should be $d(v_0, u) < k$, and the other two $\ge$. Because if $d(v_0, u) = k$, then the retraction would also map some vertex to $v_k \not\in C$.

Comment: @user Indeed you are correct. I've fixed it properly this time :P

Comment: @BrandonduPreez I think there is a problem. If a vertex not on the cycle is adjacent to $v_{k-1}$, it distance will be two, but we can't retract it to $v_2$. I think you can fix this by using the distance computed after removing the edge $v_{k-1}v_0$